# How to count matches in each row against value in another row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sets of data, one with each user's choice of characteristics for their perfect pet, and another with the complete list of characteristics matched to each pet.

I want a code that uses the answers as reference, and goes through each pet (all characteristics in a row), and counts the matching characteristics from the answer. After it has counted this score for all the pets, it should return the pet with the highest score.

Pet data is in this format, with various other characteristics mapped
[image: the pet data is in this format currently, with various other characteristics mapped]

I have this to count the matches:

```
If Sheet2.Range("aj3").Value = "yes" Then
    Sheet2.Range("ak3").Value = WorksheetFunction.Count(WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("a2:k2"), Sheet2.Range("b3:ai3")))
Else: Sheet2.Range("ak3").Value = "Not Compatible
```

Struggling with running this for each row and returning the corresponding value with the highest score.

Comment: I have a feeling (at the risk of without seeing your data) that this could be achieved with formulas. Possible to see your data? Importantly, are you open to getting this solved with formulas?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, I was able to find the answer for a particular user, however I believe to be able to automate it to return answers for all the users, I'll have to use VBA macros. Happy to be corrected if not?

Comment: So if I am not wrong this can be solved using a helper column. Also I am guessing the other set of data where the user makes choices are the headers like `Apartment, small house... etc`?if yes then the best way to do this and I might be wrong is to have only YES/NO values in the above table. In the helper column simply use a formula to match and count the characteristics and pull that formula down.

Comment: Let me know if you are interested in an example using the above YES/NO method?

Answer (score 0):

Tilak, consider this option in the vein of Siddharth's recommendation to use a helper column (or two) to solve this through functions rather than VBA:

[image: Image of spreadsheet]

I added a column to score how well each pet matches the potential home being evaluated ("Overall Score" in Column K), then a column to rank the scores ("Rank" in Column L).

The basic formula in the "Overall Score" column just looks at each cell and compares it to the analogous cell in Sheet1. Since Excel sees TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0, I just summed the results. Here's the basic formula:

```
=SUM(B3=$K$3,C3=$L$3,D3=$M$3,E3=$N$3,F3=$O$3,G3=$P$3)
```

I stepped it up a notch so that I could to make it look up whatever I typed in the cell directly under "Overall Score" (cell K2, in my case). It looks more complicated than it really is:

```
=SUM(B3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,2,FALSE),C3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,3,FALSE),D3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,4,FALSE),E3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,5,FALSE),F3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,6,FALSE),G3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,7,FALSE),H3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,8,FALSE),I3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,9,FALSE),J3=VLOOKUP($K$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$J$3,10,FALSE))
```

Regarding the VBA that you wrote, I was unable to get it to function in the way that you say you're getting it to function. But if you still want to go that route, the answer to running it for each row is to create a loop. Perhaps something like this:

```
Dim AvailCell, AvailRange As Range

Set AvailRange = Sheet2.Range("AJ2:AJ10")

For Each AvailCell In AvailRange
    If AvailCell.Value = "Yes" Then
        AvailCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Count(WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("a2:k2"), Range(AvailCell.Offset(0, -29).Address & ":" & AvailCell.Offset(0, -1).Address))) ' Sheet2.Range("b3:ai3")))
    Else
        AvailCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Not Compatible"
    End If
Next
```

But again, the WorksheetFunctions you're using did not function for me in the way that I think you're wanting them to function.